# Streaming large .mp4 file from Google Cloud Storage plays without video track, audio only

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video, google-cloud-storage, streaming, mp4

I have a large (> 1 GB) video uploaded in a GCP Cloud Storage Bucket. If I download the whole file, the playback will show both video and audio correctly. However, if I try to stream the video in my frontend app or with the preview button within the Object details page in the GCP Console, the video plays back only with audio and no video track. The **Content-Type** of the object is set to **video/mp4**.

I have tested this with smaller videos (< 30 MB) and the streaming works properly.

I'm not sure I can modify content delivery from GCP in any other ways.

Comment: _`"If I download the whole file, the playback will show both video and audio correctly."`_ which browser (and O.S) are you testing the downloaded file with?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage does not provide options to separate or control the download of the video and soundtracks. The effects that you think you are seeing are browser actions and not selective content delivery by Cloud Storage.

Changing the HTTP **Content-Type** only affects how the browser interprets the data. That header does not affect the data delivered by Cloud Storage.